# USPTO nonprovisional application before national application

Tags: uspto, pct

I want to apply for USPTO nonprovisional utility patent as a Turkish. How can I learn if US has any agreement between Turkish Patent Office (Turkey) in order to prevent international applications before national applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WIPO](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/texts/nat_sec.html) has quite a good list of foreign filing requirements for each country. I've never known it to be wrong (though there's always a first time).

According to WIPO, if a Turkish resident has an invention concerning a "subject of significance for national security", they must first apply with the Turkish Patent Institute. This suggests that for any other invention, you would be fine to file directly with the USPTO (or any other office). Best to check with a Turkish patent attorney though.